# Matplot: indicate with dots on the graph if conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                     time   price   direction   event   High_cross  movement_up triggered_up    
    26  2019-01-01 11:37:57.434 0.00224242  up   crossing up   True  False  
    27  2019-01-01 11:37:57.784 0.00224243  up     0         False  False           
    28  2019-01-01 11:38:38.575 0.00224171  up     0         False  False           
    29  2019-01-01 11:38:57.602 0.00224311  up     0         False  False       
    30  2019-01-01 11:39:21.907 0.00224473  up     0         True   movement        
    31  2019-01-01 11:39:40.320 0.00224422  up     0         True   True        
    32  2019-01-01 11:40:16.966 0.00224697  up     0         True   True    
    33  2019-01-01 11:41:16.966 0.00224694  down    0        True   Movement
    34  2019-01-01 11:42:16.966 0.00224674  down    0        false  false
    35  2019-01-01 11:43:16.966 0.00224672  down crossing down false    false Yes
```

Hello, what I would need is to indicate with a dot a specific value on a graph when it meets certain conditions. For now I only plotted the price against the time like that:

`df['price'] = df.price.astype(float)
df.plot(y='price', x='time')`

What I would need now is when the column `High_cross` is set `True` and on the same row the column `movement_up` is equal to `movement` put a dot at the price. Do the same when the column `event` is equal to `crossing down` and `triggered up` to `Yes`. And finally the same when `event` is `crossing down` and `triggered up` is equal to `No`.... I looked a bit in the documentation but I was unable to find an explanation on how to use multiple conditions... any help? thanks!

This is what I tried to find the rows which meet my conditions:

```
`movement= df[(df.High_cross == True) & (df.movement_up == 'movement')]
price_movement = movement.price

crossing_yes = df[(df.event == 'crossing down') & (df.triggered_up == 'Yes')]
price_crossing_yes = crossing_yes.price

crossing_no = df[(df.event == 'crossing down') & (df.triggered_up == 'No')]
price_crossing_no = crossing_no.price`
```

But I am stuck on how to plot these prices on the graph..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the extracted values using

```
plt.scatter(movement['time'].tolist(), price_movement.tolist(), marker='o')
plt.scatter(crossing_yes['time'].tolist(), price_crossing_yes.tolist(), marker='.')
plt.scatter(crossing_no['time'].tolist(), price_crossing_no.tolist(), marker='+')
```

`movement`, `crossing_yes`, and `crossing_no` are `DataFrame` objects, so the column must be specified . This is equivalent to e.g.

```
time_movement = movement.time
plt.scatter(time_movement.tolist(), price_movement.tolist())
```

But slightly less verbose. You can of course compress this further by performing the 
filtering inline

```
plt.scatter(df[(df.High_cross == True)&(df.movement_up == 'movement')]['time'].tolist(), 
            df[(df.High_cross == True)&(df.movement_up == 'movement')]['price'].tolist(),
            marker='o')
plt.scatter(df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'Yes')]['time'].tolist(),
            df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'Yes')]['price'].tolist(),
            marker='.')
plt.scatter(df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'No')]['time'].tolist(), 
            df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'No')]['price'].tolist(), 
            marker='+')
```

Which is slightly more concise and lends itself to looping but does require a second pass that would otherwise be less intensive.

Here is a complete example using the data provided

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
     [['2019-01-01 11:37:57.434', 0.00224242, 'up', 'crossing up', True, False],
      ['2019-01-01 11:37:57.784', 0.00224243, 'up', 0, False, False],
      ['2019-01-01 11:38:38.575', 0.00224171, 'up', 0, False, False],
      ['2019-01-01 11:38:57.602', 0.00224311, 'up', 0, False, False],
      ['2019-01-01 11:39:21.907', 0.00224473, 'up', 0, True, 'movement'],
      ['2019-01-01 11:39:40.320', 0.00224422, 'up', 0, True, True],        
      ['2019-01-01 11:40:16.966', 0.00224697, 'up', 0, True, True],
      ['2019-01-01 11:41:16.966', 0.00224694, 'down', 0, True, 'Movement'],
      ['2019-01-01 11:42:16.966', 0.00224674, 'down', 0, False, False],
      ['2019-01-01 11:43:16.966', 0.00224672, 'down', 'crossing down', 
        False, False, 'Yes']])

df.columns = ['time', 'price', 'direction', 'event', 'High_cross', 
              'movement_up', 'triggered_up']

df['price'] = df.price.astype(float)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.plot(y='price', x='time', legend=False)
plt.scatter(df[(df.High_cross == True)&(df.movement_up == 'movement')]['time'].tolist(), 
            df[(df.High_cross == True)&(df.movement_up == 'movement')]['price'].tolist(),
            marker='o')
plt.scatter(df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'Yes')]['time'].tolist(),
            df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'Yes')]['price'].tolist(),
            marker='.')
plt.scatter(df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'No')]['time'].tolist(), 
            df[(df.event == 'crossing down')&(df.triggered_up == 'No')]['price'].tolist(), 
            marker='+')
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

[image: Price over time]